# Azure Resource Group with resources in different regions

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-regions

We want to use Snowflake. As you maybe know, Snoflake is only available in specific regions on major hypersclaers like Microsoft Azure:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-regions#europe-middle-east-regions

In Germany, there is no region. Next one is in the Netherlands. All our services are hosted in the Azure Germany Frankfurt Region - germanywestcentral.

My question is: Is it possible to deploy Snowflake in the region on Netherlands and have all the other resources in Frankfurt? Is this possible? Or do i need to create multiple subscriptions with VNET peering for this scenario?

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by “all other resources”? What are the scenarios where the location of your Snowflake instance has any effect on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deploy resources to different regions inside a resource group.